# какой паттерн проектирования выбрать c#

Tags: c#, winforms, шаблоны-проектирования

я новичок в программировании. дошел до мысли, что без паттернов дальнейшее обучение приведёт к плохому стилю и привычкам.
сейчас я планирую с целью получения опыта и обучения написать простую программу органайзер с помощью WinForms.
программа состоит из формы, на которой отображаются задачи. задачи можно добавлять, изменять и удалять. ну и сортировать.
как её сделать я знаю. но вот как её сделать с помощью паттерна и какой паттерн следует выбрать и почему, не знаю. все попытки изучить паттерны взрывают мой мозг. я не знаю с чего начать. поэтому начну с Вашего совета. и буду на конкретном примере делать конкретную программу и разбираться в одном конкретном паттерне, чтобы максимально эффективно его изучить.
прошу дать совет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75396/discussion-on-question-by-cancoder-----c).